# Check if set of columns have scientific value

Tags: postgresql

I need to check if 4 columns (varchar) have at least 1 row with scientific connotation values (E+)
I'm doing this for a single column:

```
declare
    _ean int;
begin
    t_query = '
        select count(*)  from mytable where trim_to_null(myfield) is not null and (trim_to_null(myfield) ilike '%E+%');';
    execute t_query into _ean;

    IF _ean != 0 THEN

        RAISE NOTICE 'EAN has a scientific connotation, please review the file';
        return 'Error The file contains % EAN with scientific connotation';
    
    END IF;
    return null;
```

It works ok for this one column but now I need to also check 4 more columns and I need to tell on which column the scientific connotation was found, I could do this by multiples "IF" to check on each column but I bet there's a better way to do it in one sentence, and return the column/s name which had the scientific connotation.

Comment: Why tag PostgreSQL and T-SQL? T-SQL is used by SQL Server and sybase, not PostgreSQL. This doesn't look like valid T-SQL.

Comment: Why the dynamic SQL, that seems completely useless. What data types are those columns?

Comment: I removed the T-SQL tag, that was an error, my bad.

Comment: The columns are varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you don't need dynamic SQL for that.

Also, storing numbers as strings is really bad practice – your queries get more complicated, and somebody could store non-numbers as well.

All that said, I thing your query ignored the fact that scientific notation could also be `1e-7` or `1e4`.

So I think the query should contain

```
WHERE trim_to_null(myfield) ILIKE '%E%'
```

or, if you want to check the number for correctness, something like

```
WHERE trim_to_null(myfield) ~ '^[+-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?[eE][+-]?[0-9]+$'
```

But to your original question:

You could run

```
SELECT id, col1_is_ean, col2_is_ean, col3_is_ean
FROM (SELECT id,
             col1 ILIKE '%E%' AS col1_is_ean,
             col2 ILIKE '%E%' AS col2_is_ean,
             col3 ILIKE '%E%' AS col3_is_ean
      FROM mytable) AS q
WHERE col1_is_ean OR col2_is_ean OR col3_is_ean;
```